# Breakpoint in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem in break points, when I insert a breakpoint and run the program, it hit the breakpoint. But the system showing me the disassembly code instead of my code, can anyone help me how to fix this? I was struggling for almost 2 hours, please help me, I am using MS.Visual Studio 2005.
here is the snapshot of disassembly.

I tried to open the debug and it doesn't gave me any option to disable this, thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: How are you setting the breakpoint now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to

`Debug->Options and Settings`,

uncheck the box for

`Enable address-level debugging`

[image]

Comment: I see you are a new user. If it helps you, don't forget mark it as accepted. This will help you in further questions because people will know that you accept answers, and it will add points to you. Even more, accept answers in your old questions.